# Can't access static member function C++

Tags: c++

I have a static member of a class of type map. but whenever I try to access it I always get an error. For example

```
// a.h
class a {
    public:
        static map<string, int>m;
    a() {
    }
    ~a() {
    }
};

// a.cpp
    a::m['ADD']=1;
```

this is the error I get = "Size of array has non-integer type 'const char[4]"
I also get a weird error in the linker.

Comment: I think `'ADD'` should be `"ADD"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *define* the map before you can use it:

```
std::map<std::string, int> a::m = std::map<std::string, int>{{"ADD", 1}};
```

This will initialize it to a map holding one element with key `std::string("ADD")` and value `1`.

Note also, use double quotes for string literals.

Comment: I did this exactly but I get this error
"C++ requires a type specifier  for all declarations" 

??

Comment: @I.el-sayed Oops, sorry, I had missed the type. I have fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error: You are using single-quotes when you probably meant to use double quotes.

Linker error: When defining static variables of a class, you also have to define them in a cpp file somewhere. Add the following line to your cpp file:

```
map<string, int> a::m;
```

Comment: I did that but I still have an error ..
Now what is in the cpp is this 

    std::map<std::string, int>a::m;

    a::m = std::map<std::string, int>{
        {"ADD", 0},
        {"MUL", 1},
    };

I still get this error 
"C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"

Comment: is your line:
    a::m['ADD']=1;
inside of a function call? If not, that could be what the compiler is complaining about.